# jslint4java tolerates unused variables

Tags: javascript, jslint, jslint4java

I have downloaded and set up jslint4java. When I use the following command:

```
java -jar C:\...\jslint4java-2.0.0.jar --encoding UTF-8 --indent 4 --browser *.js
```

Although there are some unused variables in the file, jsLint does *not* complain about them. I want it to. But I did not find any appropriate option in the [command line docu](http://jslint4java.googlecode.com/svn/docs/2.0.0/cli.html).

Any advice on what setting I am missing there?

Note: This is about variables not method parameters. I found the `--unparam` option, but it is about parameters, and it is for *dis*-abling rather than for *en*-abling the check. I do not use this option, so the check is supposed to work.

The [jslint for Visual Studio plug-in](http://jslint4vs2010.codeplex.com/) *does* complain about the unused variables.

Simple code example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var a = 0,
        b = 1;

    alert(b);
});
```

In this example, the jslint for Visual Studio plug-in correctly complains about variable `a` not being used, whilst jslint4java doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a code sample where it complains?  If the result is different to jslint.com with the same options selected, it's a bug in jslint4java (though please bear in mind that jslint4java may be running a slightly older version of JSLint).

---

I've figured out what's up. It's not necessarily a bug in jslint4java. You do see the "unused variable" warning if you specify `--report report` on the command line. JSLint produces an optional HTML report on your code in addition to any warnings. That must be what the VS plugin is using. I've got no idea why they're not surfaced as regular JSLint warnings.

You're not the only one to notice this: http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/jslint_com/message/2526

Comment: OK, I've figured out what's up.  It's not necessarily a bug in jslint4java.  You do see the "unused variable" warning if you specify `--report report` on the command line.  JSLint produces an optional HTML-report on your code in addition to any warnings.  That must be what the VS plugin is using.  I've got no idea why they're not surfaced as regular JSLint warnings.

Comment: I see. Very clever! Can you include this in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

The `unparam` option controls unused parameters.  Default is that it will complain.  If jslint4java doesn't, it's probably a bug.  Internally to jslint, unused parameters are passed in a separate field after the analysis, jslint4java might have missed it.

Comment: I also found the `unparam` option, but as you say, it is for *disabling* the complaints, and if I get it right, it is about parameters rather than variables. (var declarations)